# Why does Global variable show ambiguity error even if there isno local variable?

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, global-variables, ambiguous, ambiguity

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int move=0;
void main()
{
 ++move;
}
```

### ##Error: "move" is ambiguous

How do I overcome this?

---

Comment: Because of [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) and [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)? Try to avoid `using namespace std;` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Stop typing `using namespace std;`

It happens because you injected a huge amount of symbols from `namespace std` into the global namespace, then happened to use one of them.  `std` is big, and any header can include any other.  Simply don't `using namespace std;`.

If you must, do it locally in a function, or even better `using std::what_you_need;` explicitly locally in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `::` before variable name, means from *global* namespace.

Correct code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int move=0;

int main()
{
    ++::move;
    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int move=0;

int main()
{
    using ::move;

    ++move;
    return 0;
}
```